# Que veut dire « manger la feuille » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, sport

J'ai un logiciel pour mon iPhone qui me permet d'écouter les stations de radio françaises. J'étais en train d'écouter RMC et le commentateur d'un match de foot a dit qu'un des joueurs a « mangé la feuille ».

Pourquoi il aurait dit ça ? Y a-t-il d'autres situations communes où on pourrait utiliser cette expression ?

Comment: À moins qu'un joueur ne se soit attaqué aux oreilles d'un autre, l'expression doit faire référence à la feuille de match (vive le jargon footballistique !).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je ne connaissais pas l'expression. Heureusement, on trouve quelques blogs qui l'expliquent. C'est un terme spécifique aux jeux de ballon, surtout au football mais aussi au handball ou au basket. D'après [Gilonimo](http://gilonimo.over-blog.net/article-2951175.html) :

> Manger la feuille ne signifie pas que le joueur est végétarien mais qu’il a raté un But tout fait.
>
> Rater un but tout fait ne veut pas dire que le joueur n’est même pas capable de construire un but qui est déjà fait mais qu’il a loupé une occasion en or.

Bon, je passe la suite, ça veut dire qu'un joueur a tiré vers le but, que le but semblait facile à marquer (au moins du point de vue du spectateur), mais que le joueur a raté le but.

[Choa-Garra-Charrua](http://choa-garra-charrua.blogspot.fr/2010/12/on-parle-tous-football-manger-la.html) explique plaisamment comment utiliser cette expression dans la vie de tous les jours (d'un spectateur de foot).

On trouve souvent l'expression plus complète « manger la feuille de match ». (La feuille de match, c'est une feuille de papier où l'on note les noms des joueurs et le nombre de buts qu'ils marquent.) Je pense que l'expression est similaire à  « [manger son chapeau](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/manger-son-chapeau.php) » : quelque chose que l'on fait par dégoût d'avoir échoué sur un but  que l'on pensait acquis. Manger la feuille de match peut être une punition infligée au joueur qui a ainsi raté une occasion de marquer un point.

L'expression se trouve dans la variante « bouffer la feuille » sur le [lexique du football de Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_du_football#B), qui lui donne le sens plus général d'un joueur dont l'action cause la perte du match par son équipe.

Pour en savoir plus, Google Books suggère deux références que je n'ai pas consultées :

- *Argots et néologismes du sport : dictionnaire historique et critique (du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle à nos jours)*, par Albert Doillon (Les Amis du lexique français, 1993).
- « Un Lexique-grammaire du football », par Paul Sabatier, dans *Linguisticae investigationes* 21:1, 1997.